# Why my NodeJS app after packing with Zeit pkg is running as a background process in Linux mint cinnamon 19.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, child-process, zeit-pkg

**Hello!**

I am using Linux mint cinnamon 19.1 and I have some NodeJS project and want packing to a single executable using [zeit pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg) targeting to platform Linux and Windows. Process packaging is running well, but...

**The problem is**

When I open that executable with double click the app is running in background process automatically in Linux mint cinnamon 19.1 it didn't show the terminal, the error, also is hard to stop the process I have to do some `netstat` and `kill processid`

I found the same [issue](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/900) and also this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/925) and have not been answered

**My solution**

I have a solution that comes to mind with `child_process` modules, and `spawn('gnome-terminal').exec('node my-node.app')` and of course it didn't work because `.exec()` diferrent prototype, and for now I am still can't find how to do spawn terminal and exec the command **How to do spawn terminal and exec the command in the terminal that I have spawned**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just only need use `.exec()` not `.spawn()`

See [this for more detail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974756/how-can-i-open-a-extra-console-and-run-a-program-in-it-with-one-command)

```
const os = require('os');
const child_process = require('child_process');

if (os.platform() === 'linux') {
    child_process.exec('gnome-terminal -x bash -c "node your-node.js; exec bash"', 
    function(err, out, derr) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(out);
        console.log(derr);
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow Thanks! You save my day :)